# What is the reason define unknown enum in separate class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

In Apple Lister example https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Listings/Objective_C_ListerKit_AAPLListInfo_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014701-Objective_C_ListerKit_AAPLListInfo_m-DontLinkElementID_35

they have this code to define additional undefined state of color enum

```
#define AAPLListColorUndefined ((AAPLListColor)-1)
...
#undef AAPLListColorUndefined
```

but why don't they just add this to the class where they define others color

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, AAPLListColor) {
    AAPLListColorGray = 0,
    AAPLListColorBlue,
    AAPLListColorGreen,
    AAPLListColorYellow,
    AAPLListColorOrange,
    AAPLListColorRed
};
```

Is there a reason behind this ? or just a personal style without any benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `AAPLListColorUndefined` is used *only* in the file it's declared (and is even specifically undefined at the end of that file.) It's basically a helper value that's only used in that class (to keep track of whether the colour has been set yet.) Unlike the other values, it's only useful in that one class. So, that's design reason one: it's not *really* a colour value; it's basically just a flag used in that specific class.

A second reason is that the compiler will check NS_ENUM values for completeness in `switch` statements. Try adding AAPLListColorUndefined into the enum itself—you'll now see compiler warnings for `switch` statements like this:

```
// Warning: Enumeration value 'AAPLListColorUndefined' not handled in switch
switch (listColor) {
    case AAPLListColorGray:     return _grayColor;
    case AAPLListColorBlue:     return _blueColor;
    case AAPLListColorGreen:    return _greenColor;
    case AAPLListColorYellow:   return _yellowColor;
    case AAPLListColorOrange:   return _orangeColor;
    case AAPLListColorRed:      return _redColor;
}
```

...because the compiler can see that the undefined value isn't being handled. As the value can only *be* undefined in that one specific class, it makes sense *not* to have it available in the NS_ENUM for the other classes, as that would force you to handle it, when you know your colour value can't logically can't ever be undefined in them. (In the other files, a default grey colour is used, so there's no need for an "undefined" value—the colour is always defined.)

So, that's kind of the "flip side" of the design reason: as well as only being useful in the one file it's defined, it's specifically *not* useful in the files it's not being used in.

This is very tidy code, I'd say. If you were to add the undefined colour as part of the enum, then you'd need to do *something* in every switch statement that used the enum, even if it was only having a `default:` case that did nothing, or raised an error that you knew would never happen.

Or, you could get away without having the undefined value at all in `AAPLListInfo.m` by setting the colour property to a default value, say grey, like the other files, but then you'd need an extra flag—a boolean, probably—to indicate whether the list info has been fetched.

Comment: It looks like they tried to mimic Swift optionals here, didn't they?

Comment: @MichałCiuba Yes; in Swift you'd declare the property as optional in the ListInfo class, and just check to see whether it was nil or not to see if it had been loaded yet. Which would be a bit less obscure, and is a good example of where optionals can come in handy.

Comment: This make sense, that undefined thing mimic the state not the real color value.